# Quarkus not serving swagger on local machine

Tags: java, swagger-ui, quarkus

I'm trying to run Quarkus from my local machine (windows). It works. However, when I go to the landing page, it does not serve swagger.

The log shows:

```
21:29:04 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
21:29:04 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, hibernate-validator, micrometer, mutiny, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-openapi, swagger-ui, vertx, vertx-web]
21:29:30 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-10) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:21:29:30 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui HTTP/1.1" 302 -
21:29:30 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-3) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:21:29:30 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
21:29:30 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-4) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:21:29:30 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/theme-feeling-blue.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
21:29:30 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-5) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:21:29:30 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
21:29:30 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-2) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:21:29:30 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
21:29:30 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-1) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:21:29:30 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

There's probably something obvious. It shows the download dialogue for openapi and the rest calls I define they simply work.

Exactly the same maven project runs on my colleagues machine and it deploys / runs on docker. I'm looking already for a couple of days, but I don't see the solution. I looked at the hosts file.

How can I debug this? Any hints on what might be wrong? I'm a newbie on Quarkus (just busy finding my way around)

The full log:

```
2:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-13) requestBegin /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui: {CONNECTED_SOCKET_SAMPLE=io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeLongTaskTimer$CompositeSample@2041381}, io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@2cc5a745
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-13) responseEnd: io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@2cc5a745, io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl@41ed01b5
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-13) requestBegin /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css: {CONNECTED_SOCKET_SAMPLE=io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeLongTaskTimer$CompositeSample@2041381}, io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@5e89e630
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-4) requestBegin /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/theme-feeling-blue.css: {CONNECTED_SOCKET_SAMPLE=io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeLongTaskTimer$CompositeSample@4c7b1d36}, io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@40364d3a
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) requestBegin /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/style.css: {CONNECTED_SOCKET_SAMPLE=io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeLongTaskTimer$CompositeSample@2582ead0}, io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@5b247e88
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) requestBegin /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js: {CONNECTED_SOCKET_SAMPLE=io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeLongTaskTimer$CompositeSample@2a0e7a80}, io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@686abd43
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) requestBegin /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js: {CONNECTED_SOCKET_SAMPLE=io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeLongTaskTimer$CompositeSample@718a2eb0}, io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@5a754f7f
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.ver.htt.run.ForwardedParser] (executor-thread-1) Recalculated absoluteURI to http://localhost:8080/gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/style.css
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-1) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /swagger-ui/style.css
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-1) {text/css=org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue@3e8, */*=org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue@64}
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (executor-thread-1) responseEnd: io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@5b247e88, io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl@37a17692
22:59:36 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-1) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:22:59:36 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.ver.htt.run.ForwardedParser] (executor-thread-6) Recalculated absoluteURI to http://localhost:8080/gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/theme-feeling-blue.css
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-6) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /swagger-ui/theme-feeling-blue.css
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-6) {text/css=org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue@3e8, */*=org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue@64}
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.ver.htt.run.ForwardedParser] (executor-thread-1) Recalculated absoluteURI to http://localhost:8080/gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (executor-thread-6) responseEnd: io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@40364d3a, io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl@4ba14ca1
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-1) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js
22:59:36 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-6) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:22:59:36 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/theme-feeling-blue.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-1) {*/*=org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue@3e8}
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.ver.htt.run.ForwardedParser] (executor-thread-6) Recalculated absoluteURI to http://localhost:8080/gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-6) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-6) {text/css=org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue@3e8, */*=org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue@64}
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (executor-thread-1) responseEnd: io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@5a754f7f, io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl@9eb2123
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (executor-thread-6) responseEnd: io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@5e89e630, io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl@911f62c
22:59:36 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-6) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:22:59:36 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
22:59:36 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-1) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:22:59:36 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.ver.htt.run.ForwardedParser] (executor-thread-7) Recalculated absoluteURI to http://localhost:8080/gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-7) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-7) {*/*=org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue@3e8}
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (executor-thread-7) responseEnd: io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@686abd43, io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl@7ba23767
22:59:36 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-7) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:22:59:36 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-13) requestBegin /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js: {CONNECTED_SOCKET_SAMPLE=io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeLongTaskTimer$CompositeSample@2041381}, io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@35450f9e
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.ver.htt.run.ForwardedParser] (executor-thread-7) Recalculated absoluteURI to http://localhost:8080/gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-7) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-7) {*/*=org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue@3e8}
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (executor-thread-7) responseEnd: io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@35450f9e, io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl@21e48dcf
22:59:36 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (executor-thread-7) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:22:59:36 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-13) requestBegin /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/favicon.ico: {CONNECTED_SOCKET_SAMPLE=io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeLongTaskTimer$CompositeSample@2041381}, io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@7d2b0755
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-13) requestReset: io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@7d2b0755
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.ver.htt.run.ForwardedParser] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-13) Recalculated absoluteURI to http://localhost:8080/gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/favicon.ico
22:59:36 INFO  [io.qua.htt.access-log] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-13) 127.0.0.1 - - 20/Jan/2021:22:59:36 +0100 "GET /gm/gmw-v1.1/swagger-ui/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-7) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /swagger-ui/favicon.ico
22:59:36 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-7) {image/webp=org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue@3e8, */*=org.jboss.resteasy.core.request.QualityValue@3e8}
22:59:36 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (executor-thread-7) responseEnd: io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.RequestMetric@7d2b0755, io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl@5009f63c
```

Comment: Hi,.no answers from me but just a couple of ideas - wondering if it's possible to bump up log level to debug for any more clues?  Also, I notice a 302 response to the main get - can you look in developer tools to see the location of the redirect

Comment: The fact that the get is logged means the server is receiving your request I think, so that rules out docker issues like listening on VM IP address rather than localhost. I guess developer tools might be the best next step - you can see the server end in your logs so see what is happening at the client end

Comment: @Chris Thanks. What do you mean with "developer tools". Did I miss something in the documentation? I'll try to bump the log level. Kind of stupid from me that I did not think of that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you are hitting this in a browser then Dev tools there - I'm guessing you are using a browser rather than postman or curl or similar, but I don't know enough about quarkus to know how you would access the swagger docs

Comment: So network activity to see the 302 response will show where it is redirecting to, it *may* give a clue

Comment: ah.. I get it..

Comment: Hmm... it cannot find: swagger-ui-bundle.js (Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined) .. but where it should be obtained from.. I'll investigate

Comment: Ah, explains why you're not getting what you expect. I guess it's something to do with how everything is getting bundled up/built as I guess it is a file that should be included. Is this getting built into an artifact or are you just running it from an IDE - if the former then I guess you have a jar/war/tar file, maybe worth looking in there, also maybe worth looking at build logging, does build report any problems? Anyway I'm still guessing so all the above may not make any real sense

Comment: Actually, you put me on the right track. I fixed it (see answer below). Thanks

Comment: Brilliant, so glad you got it working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems that Quarkus stores its web-resources in the /tmp folder (see: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12577). I went to the /tmp folder in git-bash and just deleted all the files/folders (that the OS allowed me to delete).

And voila, it started to work after that.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, but just want to contribute with this topic: On macOS, the temporary directory is not `/tmp`, it is defined on the environment variable `$TMPDIR`.